# Capture and forwarding of network traffic from a particular application on Windows

Tags: c++, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, winpcap

I need to capture network traffic that is going in/out of a particular application. The main issue is that I would like to do this in a blocking fashion -- i.e. capture the traffic, perform some analysis and encryption/decryption on it and then forward it along its regular route. So, it must use some sort of a blocking mechanism.

Is there some code or a library that makes this easy to do on Windows (Server 2008 or Win7 will do)? Any C++ (or Python/Java) classes or libraries that already exist?

I intend for the solution to also execute on the same machine as the target app and have administrative privileges.

Any pointers to code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

p.s.: I have been looking at WinPcap but from my (limited) understanding, it can't filter/block based on specific applications. Is that right, or did I miss something? Any other solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

For this you should look at [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html).  Unlike regular packet sniffers (like winpcap), WinDivert also has the ability to *block/filter* packets, so it might be what you are looking for. Disclosure: WinDivert is my own project.